# JavaEE object oriented networking

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, serversocket

I'd like clarification in regard to network OOP. For example using the client-server model, like a messenger, you have two programs. When the client program is run an object of it is instantiated. A `Socket` is then instantiated inside the client program and connected to the server programs `ServerSocket` using the `ServerSocket`'s `accept()` method. According to the documentation that creates a new `Socket` inside the server program. In my experience any time the word create is used in Java its referring to an object so are there now two objects for one client `Socket`? One on the client program and one on the server? Is it possible to instantiate an object in a client program from a server program or the other way around?

And finally if I use the `static` modifier to create my `Socket` in the client program normally that would allow only one object of it to be created so if the `Socket` on the `Socket` in  the client program is normally not the same `Socket`as in the server program, referring to the objects created, is there now only one object of it shared between the two programs?

Just for to be clear I'm not talking about multiple client connections, I'm just trying to understand the basic mechanics of a client's `Socket` connection to a server's `ServerSocket` as well as figure out what I can and cant do via that connection but once I understand it I can experiment on my own time.

I hope I'm not over thinking this. Thanks in advance for your help :-).

Comment: I've removed the references to Java EE, and thrown in some paragraph breaks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your question doesn't have anything to do with Java EE. Sockets are part of Java SE.

You also don't understand what `static` means. `static` scopes a variable to a class, rather than scoping it to an instance of a class. It doesn't limit the number of objects created. And each JVM has its own objects and classes, which are not shared with any other JVM over the network. Storing an object into a static variable `foo` of class A in the client JVM won't have any impact on what is stored in `A.foo` on the server.

I don't understand why you're so concerned about the number of socket objects created. A socket is just that: an endpoint for a communication between two parties. Each party has its own endpoint, connected to the endpoint of the other party. A bit like when you phone a friend: you use a phone, and your friend also uses one, and the two phones are connected with each other.

Comment: but the client programs aren't connected. each is connected through the server, I'm trying to figure out where the best place to handle the communication between the clients is.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, yes, you are absolutely correct that you end up with two `Socket` objects for the same connection, one in the client program and one in the server. However, it would be a mistake to think of these as being in any way the 'same' object. In ordinary language, 'socket' is where a connection plugs into something; a connection between two things has two sockets, one at each end. A networking `Socket` is just the same - you have one in the client program and one in the server program.

You also have the `ServerSocket` in the server program, but that's something quite different. That's not really a socket, it's a device for making sockets. In the original Berkeley sockets API, this was modelled as being a kind of socket (mistakenly so?), so it's named accordingly in Java.

You ask whether a server program can create objects in the client program. You imply that the business with sockets is an example of the client creating an object in the server program. Neither of those things are the case. The `Socket` in the server program is created entirely by the server code.

Now, there is a thing called [serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/index.html) which lets you take objects in one program, encode them as bytes to send across the network using sockets, and then reconstitute new objects from those bytes at the other end. This doesn't allow one program to remotely manipulate another, and it doesn't create objects that are in two programs simultaneously, but it does let two cooperating programs copy objects from one to the other.

As for `static`, yes, as JB says, you've misunderstood this. If you declare a variable `static`, that means that it belongs to the class it's declared in, not instances of the class it's declared in, so there will only be one copy of the variable in that program, rather than one per instance of the class. However, it has no effect across programs. Different programs have completely separate universes of variables, and so each has its own copy of `static` variables.

Comment: I'm sorry i think i did a poor job describing static, for example if i create a List in a class then create several objects if that and add them to in the constructor as they created that list will have the same amount of objects no matter where i refer to it from, correct? And thank you those comments were very informative, i understand this isn't the place to get an education but perhaps you could recommend a good book?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying about static with your example; your sentence is malformed and i can't really make head nor tail of it.

Comment: As for things to read, i think you need a solid introduction to networking. You could have a look at the [All About Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) lesson in the Java networking tutorial. The networking section of a good introductory Java book should also do the trick - i loved [Just Java](http://www.amazon.com/Just-Java%C2%BF-6th-Peter-Linden/dp/0131482114/) when i read it, but that was over a decade ago now!

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry. I posted that on my phone on my lunch break, let me try that one more time. Since you mentioned it I just want to make sure I do have the correct understanding of static. 

If I create a `static` `List` in the Foo class that contains Foo objects and add each object to the `List` from the constructor of the Foo class as the objects are created there will only be one copy of that `List` and it will contain all the objects added to it. Is that correct?

Comment: As far as introductory books go Learn Java in 24 hours and Learn Java in 21 days are both great and up to date books, maybe I need to revisit them but I don't recall either book covering too much about networking.

Comment: Concerning the static `List`, yes, that's correct - if by "only be one copy of that `List`" you really mean "only be one copy of that `List` *in any one JVM*". There would be separate copies of that list in each client and the server.